# Accessing apache http://your.server.name/server-status when proxy pass set to back end express server

Tags: apache, express

I have an apache server which has proxy pass set to back end express server listening on port 2200. I am having trouble trying to access apaches server statistics at: xyz.abc.com/server-status

Currently the express back end server is setup to route all paths to the same index.html file. So when I try to access http://xyz.abc.com/server-status
, the express server routes it to the index.html file.

**Question**: What should I change in apache setup or in express so that I am able to access http://xyz.abc.com/server-status, while all other paths are still routed to the same index.html.

**Apache httpd.conf block**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName xyz.abc.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:2200/
  LimitRequestBody 204800000
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2200/
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Expressjs block listening on port 2200:**

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../myviews/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {})
```

Comment: You could setup server-status in another VirtualHost (other name or other port).  And I hope it is on a private network, everyone can see your server info like that (Allow from all)

Comment: Would it look like below, if I add a VirtualHost for port 2300, and then access “xyz.abc.com:2300/index.html” in browser ->


<VirtualHost *:2300>
  DocumentRoot /etc/httpd/www
  ServerName xyz.abc.com
  LimitRequestBody 204800000
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: It is best to edit the question and put it there.  It is very difficult to read in comments.  But it looks ok at first glance.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for the tip Nic3500.